# how can I scroll QTableWiget in pyqt5 programmatically?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am developing a python assistant totally controlled over voice commands. Now in my program there is a screen with list of contacts made using QTableWidget and not all contacts are fit on screen, so user will have to scroll the screen...  but how?? There is a method `QTableView.scrollTo(row)` but this allow me to scroll me to specified row.  Short saying what I want just a method that allow me to scroll +5 or any level I specify every time i call that method.

Comment: What do you mean by `+5`?

Comment: I mean scroll 5 level down or 1 level down or any number.

Comment: What does a level mean: a row, a pixel or what?